# With the Google Slides API is there a ways to know the height of the text in a shape?

Tags: google-slides-api

I want to have a shape with text where the text fits neatly inside the shape.  To do this I need to know how tall the text in a textElement will be inside a given shape, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can get the information of the font size of text inside a Shape using `presentations.get` with a field mask.*

#### More Information:

The structure of a Shape with text is as follows (irrelevant fields omitted):

```json
{
  "shapeType": enum (Type),
  "text": {
    "textElements": [
      {
        "textRun": {
          "style": {
            "fontSize": {
              "magnitude": 18,
              "unit": "PT"
            },
          }
        },
      }
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

You can get this with the field mask:

```
slides/pageElements/shape/text/textElements/textRun/style/fontSize
```

#### Example Request:

```js
slides.presentations.get({
  "presentationId": "1x1iiFW0TbP3yPXRldYogXLEGT-tYfa79a2X8ZDIq8tU",
  "fields": "slides/pageElements/shape/text/textElements/textRun/style/fontSize"
});
```

**Note:** The API does not return if the text wraps across multiple lines or not. This isn't retrievable due to the nature of font sizes. If the font you were using is a monospace font, it may however be possible to work this out based on the width of the Shape and the width of the characters contained within it.

#### References:

- [Text - Page.TextStyle | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/text#Page.TextStyle)
- [Working with field masks | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/field-masks)

Comment: Thanks - the challenge is to know how many lines the text covers?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lines'?

Comment: As in if the text is so long that it does not fit on one line but wraps onto a second line.

Comment: In this case there is no way of getting that information. The API does not return it to you, and even if you were to measure the width of the Shape and the length of the string, it would depend on the content so can't do charcount unless the font is monospace. "llllll" and "mmmmmm" are the same length but the latter uses much higher screen real estate, for example.